# finding out percentage of users who made first purchase after 7 days of joining

Tags: sql, data-manipulation

I have two tables that I want to get information

[image]

What's the percentage of users who:

- sign up in 2017
- made a first purchase within 7 days of joining
- only approve transactions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose table A is for Users and table B is for Purchases and the column id is the User Id in both tables. For the average of users who made first purchase after 7 days of joined date and considering purchase_status = 1 as approved, you can do this:

```sql
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN r.first_purchase > (r.joined_date+7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS avg_situation
FROM (
    SELECT u.id, u.joined_date, MIN(p.purchase_date) AS first_purchase
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN purchases p ON u.id = p.user_id AND p.purchase_status = 1
    GROUP BY u.id, u.joined_date
) r;
```

Comment: hi Abenadal, I still don't get the right answer. I will add more info in the question.